# Mapping to have completion attempt one mode and fall back to another if no completions found

Tags: key-bindings, ins-completion

I am attempting to map `,<tab>` in insert mode to first attempt omnicompletion then fall back to `<c-p>` or `<c-x><c-p>` completion.

I have used [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) reference to successfully send a string as fallback, but I cannot get completion to work on fallback.

Attempted mappings:

```
inoremap <expr> ,<tab> pumvisible() ? "<c-p>" : 
    \'<c-x><c-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>down>" : "Print"<cr>'
```

This successfully prints 'Print' if omnicomplete detects no matches

```
inoremap <expr> ,<tab> pumvisible() ? "<c-p>" : 
    \'<c-x><c-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>down>" : "<c-x>"<cr>'
```

This enters completion mode (c-x mode) if omnicomplete detects no matches

```
inoremap <expr> ,<tab> pumvisible() ? "<c-p>" : 
    \'<c-x><c-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>down>" : "<c-x><c-p>"<cr>'
```

This prints `\<c-x><c-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>down>" : "<c-x><c-p>"<cr>` into the vim window.

What am I doing wrong that causes vim to interpret these mappings the way it is?

Note: These mappings function correctly in the case that a popup already exists or when omnicomplete detects a completion.
Also, I have attempted escaping (prefixing with `\`) all combinations of the `<c-x>` and `<c-p>` commands, but none of them were successful.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your last mapping in my vimrc and used `,<Tab>` on an incomplete word and I got the completion menu on the last match, nothing added to my buffer. Maybe check once again your syntax, that you don't missed a quote, that you don't have trailing characters, try to put everything on one line before splitting it too.

Comment: [mucomplete](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete) provides configurable fallback completion: `let g:mucomplete#chains.default  = ['omni', 'c-p']`